# svg path inside path

Tags: d3.js, svg

How i can use path inside path?

```html
    </svg>
    <svg height="210" width="400">
      <path fill="rgb(176, 60, 178)" fill-opacity="0.4" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" >
        <title>test</title>
        <path fill="rgb(14, 88, 228)" d="M100 0 L50 100 L125 100 Z" >
      </path>
    </svg>
```

In fact, this is what I want ideally:

[bagel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjolu.png)

Paint over part of the strip below, depending on the percentage.
I work in d3

Comment: just put the paths one after the other. The later path will draw on top of the earlier path.

Comment: @RobertLongson, thanks for the answer. This does not work as I need to start from the coordinate system of the first path.

Comment: getPointAtLength(getPathLength())

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*You cannot nest one path **tag** within another.*

How commented @Robert Longson

> just put the paths one after the other. The later path will draw on
> top of the earlier path.

```
<path ..... />
<path ..... />
```

```html
 <svg height="210" width="400">
      <path fill="rgb(176, 60, 178)" fill-opacity="0.4" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
        <title>test</title>
        <path fill="rgb(14, 88, 228)" d="M100 0 L50 100 L125 100 Z" />
      
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this does not work as I need to start from the coordinate system of the first path

Comment: @Yoba Fighter Thanks Can you explain in more detail what you want to get as a result? So far I saw only an error in the syntax. Do you want to get the code that implements the sectors as in your screenshot? In this case, it would be good to accept the answer and ask a new more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot [1]:

Allowed are only the following:

```
Any number of the following elements, in any order:

    animation elements
    descriptive elements
    paint server elements 

clipPath, marker, mask, script, style
```

[1] https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#PathElement

Answer (score 2):

In SVG, elements render from top to bottom: each renders on top of another. If you want one path to render over another one, put it further down:

```
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path fill="rgb(176, 60, 178)" fill-opacity="0.4" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" >
    <title>test</title>
  </path>
  <path fill="rgb(14, 88, 228)" d="M100 0 L50 100 L125 100 Z" >
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this does not work as I need to start from the coordinate system of the first path